# How can i get "Events" in a city from Custom Search API or Knowledge Graph Search API?

Tags: api, google-search, google-search-api, structured-data, google-knowledge-graph

I want to get the **events from a city** from **Custom Search Api** or **Knowledge Graph Search Api**. Is it possible?

In a normal google search it would be like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akf9W.png)
or like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N36Wa.png).

Comment: Wht have you tried so far? Post some code and you will get more help.

Comment: I'm trying to get the json directly from url like this:
  
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=event+chicago&key={API_KEY}  
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=chicago&types=Event&key={API_KEY}  

But if I try with MusicEvent (soported by schema.org) doesn't works.   For example like this:  
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=chicago&types=MusicEvent&key={API_KEY}  


I've tried other combinations in the APIs Explorer without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Google has an api for what you are looking for.  Try the [Songkick](http://www.songkick.com/developer) or [LastFM](http://www.last.fm/api) apis.